# NextJS - Attempted to call find() from the server but find is on the client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to use `.find` in the server component.

```
export async function TransactionList() {
   const transactions = await fetch('/transactions');

   return (
       <ul>
         {transactions.map(transaction => {
              const category = CATEGORIES.find(
                 (c) => c.value === transaction.category
              );
              return (...)
         }}
       </ul>
   )
}
```

However an error occurs

```
Error: Attempted to call find() from the server but find is on the client. It's not possible to invoke a client function from the server, it can only be rendered as a Component or passed to props of a Client Component.
    at eval (./components/TransactionsList/index.tsx:43:72)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Is there any workaround in this case?

Comment: very  .. how does one array method available on server and one is not, anything to do with `CATEGORIES` here ? what data it has ?

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by extracting a component in a separate file

```
export async function TransactionList() {
   const transactions = await fetch('/transactions');

   return (
       <ul>
         {transactions.map(transaction => 
              <TransactionItem transaction={transaction}/>
         )}
       </ul>
   )
}
```

TransactionItem.tsx

```
export async function TransactionItem({transaction}) {
   const category = CATEGORIES.find((c) => c.value === transaction.category);
   return (...)
}
```